# Why the control cannot be found in the current context in my ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am trying to convert my web site to web application and I am coming across some errors which is preventing me from deploying it.

I have the following .ASCX file which is located in one of my ASP.net page:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="labHours.ascx.cs" Inherits="includeNav_labHours" %>

<div style="z-index: 15; position: relative; left: 0; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 30px; font-weight: bold; color: #00A0BE;">
    LABORATORY TESTING CENTER HOURS
</div>
<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; padding-left: 15px; padding-top: 25px;">
    <div style="font-weight: bold; color: #00A0BE; position: relative; margin: 0 auto; width: 280px; height: 125px; background: url('theImages/labHoursHeader.png') no-repeat;">
        <br />
        stchester Avenue<br />
    <span id="lhWP" runat="server">White Plains</span>, New York 10629<br />
        2.6580
    <div id="dvWP" runat="server" style="width: 100%; text-align: center; padding-top: 10px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center; position: relative; margin: 0 auto; width: 280px; height: 80px; background: url('theImages/labHoursHeaderMiddle.png') repeat-y;">
        <div style="text-align: left; padding-left: 15px; width: 260px; margin: 0 auto;">
            Monday &amp; Thursday: 7AM - 7:30PM<br />
            Tuesday &amp; Wednesday: 7AM - 7PM<br />
            Friday: 7AM - 5:30PM<br />
            Saturday: 8AM - 1:30PM <br />
            Sunday: Closed
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; width: 280px; height: 26px; background: url('theImages/labHoursHeaderFooter.png') no-repeat;">
    </div>
</div>
```

The following code-behind file:

```
public partial class includeNav_labHours : UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        //DateTime test = DateTime.Now.AddHours(8);
        string time = now.ToString("T");
        //Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + time + "');", true);

        var wpInput = lhWP.InnerText;
        if (wpInput == "White Plains")
        {
            if (now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday || now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday)
            {
                if (IsTimeOfDayBetween(now, new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(19, 30, 0)))
                {
                    //OPEN MONDAY & THURSDAY
                    dvWP.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<img src='theImages/locOpen.png' alt='OPEN' title='Location is OPEN' width='60px' height='52px' />"));
                }
                else
                {
                    //CLOSE MONDAY & THURSDAY
                    dvWP.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<img src='theImages/locClose.png' alt='CLOSED' title='Location is CLOSED' width='60px' height='52px' />"));
                }
            }
            else if (now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday || now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
            {
                if (IsTimeOfDayBetween(now, new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(19, 0, 0)))
                {
                    //OPEN TUESDAY & WEDNESDAY
                    dvWP.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<img src='theImages/locOpen.png' alt='OPEN' title='Location is OPEN' width='60px' height='52px' />"));
                }
                else
                {
                    //CLOSE TUESDAY & WEDNESDAY
                    dvWP.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<img src='theImages/locClose.png' alt='CLOSED' title='Location is CLOSED' width='60px' height='52px' />"));
                }
            }
            else if (now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
            {
                if (IsTimeOfDayBetween(now, new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(17, 30, 0)))
                {
                    //OPEN FRIDAY
                    dvWP.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<img src='theImages/locOpen.png' alt='OPEN' title='Location is OPEN' width='60px' height='52px' />"));
                }
                else
                {
                    //CLOSE FRIDAY
                    dvWP.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<img src='theImages/locClose.png' alt='CLOSED' title='Location is CLOSED' width='60px' height='52px' />"));
                }
            }
            else if (now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
            {
                if (IsTimeOfDayBetween(now, new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(13, 30, 0)))
                {
                    //OPEN SATURDAY
                    dvWP.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<img src='theImages/locOpen.png' alt='OPEN' title='Location is OPEN' width='60px' height='52px' />"));
                }
                else
                {
                    //CLOSE SATURDAY
                    dvWP.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<img src='theImages/locClose.png' alt='CLOSED' title='Location is CLOSED' width='60px' height='52px' />"));
                }
            }
            else if (now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            {
                //CLOSE SUNDAY
                dvWP.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<img src='theImages/locClose.png' alt='CLOSED' title='Location is CLOSED' width='60px' height='52px' />"));
            }
        }
    }

    static public bool IsTimeOfDayBetween(DateTime time, TimeSpan startTime, TimeSpan endTime)
    {
        if (endTime == startTime)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (endTime < startTime)
        {
            return time.TimeOfDay <= endTime || time.TimeOfDay >= startTime;
        }
        else
        {
            return time.TimeOfDay >= startTime && time.TimeOfDay <= endTime;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the app, I get the following errors:

> The name 'dvWP' does not exist in the current context  c:\Users\z\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WMEXEC SLN\WMEXEC\includeNav\urgCareTime.ascx.cs   23  17  WMEXEC
>
> The name 'lhWP' does not exist in the current context  c:\Users\z\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WMEXEC SLN\WMEXEC\includeNav\urgCareTime.ascx.cs   23  17  WMEXEC

Why am I getting that error? and How do I fix it?

Comment: Did you [register your user control](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/26/tip-trick-how-to-register-user-controls-and-custom-controls-in-web-config.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, it is registered in every page I am using it in.

Comment: Is it a web site project or web application project?

Comment: Web site project it worked fine and didn't give me any issue. I am getting the error during the web application deployment.

Comment: You need to [convert it properly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/10/29/converting-a-web-site-project-to-a-web-application-project.aspx) then. Visual Studio -> Solution Tree -> <file> -> <right click> -> Convert to Web Application. So a designer file will be generated.

Comment: The designer file for the ASCX files does not add the necessary lines. Not sure why.

Comment: Delete the designer file from disk, remove it from project, click convert again. This will re-generate a designer file from markup and add the necessary identifiers/fields.

Comment: How did it work to you?

Comment: I am putting everything in and will update. Thanks.

Comment: That did not resolve the issue that I am having. Same thiing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might as well use a panel

```
<asp:Panel id="dvWP" runat="server">
```

It will become a `div` once parsed, and it should be easier to access.

Comment: I can but will it solve the issue? I can convert all HTML tag to aSPX equivalent, but it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Yes, might help indeed.

Comment: I will convert all my HTML to ASPX and hopefully it will work.

Comment: I'd say this is replacing of client-side controls with server-side controls.

Comment: Maybe you are right... I changed one to an ASPX control and it's working fine. Weird it's not taking the standard HTML tag with the runat command.

Comment: @SiKni8 I dont know the inner reasons to be honest, but using asp controls will give you more control in code-behind and also expose more property than adding a run at server to a div.

Comment: That didn't do anything :/ I am still getting the same error!!!!! I am about to go crazy. heeeeelpppppppppppppp.

Comment: @SiKni8 i thought you [said it works fine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835735/why-the-control-cannot-be-found-in-the-current-context-in-my-asp-net-web-applica/23835797?noredirect=1#comment36676512_23835797) ??

Comment: Actually you are right. I had to convert each ASCX file into a web application file to produce the .designer.cs file and it's working fine now. Thanks. Answer accepted :)